# Visual bug on edited post title within reputation list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On my profile page in the reputation section the title text of a post I edited appears in a larger font.  I thought this might be a bug since it looked a bit out of place.  Screenshot below:

[image: reputation list screenshot]

Comment: I'm lookng into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fix will be in the next deployment.